# Multiple Toggles In A Post Loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I've created a simple toggle to reveal and close a food menu. However as this is in a Wordpress Loop only the first one works.

I'm guessing because as the page builds itself out there then become multiple ID's. However I can't find anyway to tweak the JQuery / JS to not use ID's.

Any Ideas??

```
<a id="menu-toggle" class="menu-button">Menu</a>
<div class="menu-toggle-container">
    <div id="food-menu">
        <div>
            <h3><?php echo $summer_menu_item_one; ?></h3>
            <h4><?php echo $summer_menu_price_one; ?></h4>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3><?php echo $summer_menu_item_two; ?></h3>
            <h4><?php echo $summer_menu_price_two; ?></h4>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3><?php echo $summer_menu_item_three; ?></h3>
            <h4><?php echo $summer_menu_price_three; ?></h4>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3><?php echo $summer_menu_item_four; ?></h3>
            <h4><?php echo $summer_menu_price_four; ?></h4>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3><?php echo $summer_menu_item_five; ?></h3>
            <h4><?php echo $summer_menu_price_five; ?></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


$(function () {
        var foodMenu = document.getElementById('food-menu');
        var foodMenuName = document.getElementById('menu-toggle');
        $('#menu-toggle').click(function () {
            foodMenu.classList.toggle('active');
            foodMenuName.classList.toggle('active');
        });
});
```

The foodMenuName just swaps **'open menu'** text to **'close menu'**.

Comment: All IDs in HTML must be unique. I suspect if there are multiple instances, you do not have the right selector or ID.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "only the first one works"?

Comment: Multiple Id's were stoping the drop down working when the post loop printed them multiple times on the page. The answer from Twisty (below) worked a treat and solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```
$(function () {
    $('.menu-button').click(function(e) {
        var menuToggle = $(this).next(".menu-toggle-container");
        $("div", menuToggle).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

This makes use of the class and relative position of the elements. This will Add and Remove the `active` class to the food-menu upon click.

Comment: Been struggling with this all day and this solution has completely solved the issue for me. Can't thank you enough!!